# mysql: if then else query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
ID | table | article | number
1     2        2        1  
2     3        4        4
```

What I need is a query which checks whether a combination of table and article already exists.
For example (table 2 and article 2)

In this case number should be incremented by 1.
So it has to like like this now: 1 2 2 2

Otherwise (for example: table 2 and article 5) a new row should be created:
3 2 5 1

Is it possible to do this with 1 statement and how?

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score -1):

This may work for you on your DB...

```
insert into theTable 
(ID, table, article, number) 
values (3, 2, 5, 1) 
where not exists    
(select ID 
from theTable 
where table = 2 and article = 5)
```

Comment: y thanks, but what about the part if it exists ... then the number of the existing row should be incremented....

Comment: Missed that... I don't know of a way to do both unless you use a stored procedure (which would be composed of more than 1 statement).